# Dot dot dot on return from function

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Can someone explain the "dot dot dot" at the return from an observable like this for Firebase ?

```
      return actions.map(action => {
    const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Todo;
    const id = action.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  });
```

I can't find anything about at Google docs for Firebase / Angularfire.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a "spread operator and is part of modern JavaScript. It essentially replaces `data` with the key/value pairs that are in `data`.

So say that `data` is:

```
const id = 209103;
const data = { nickname: "puf", name: "Frank van Puffelen" }
```

Then:

```
return { id, ...data };
```

Is the same as:

```
return { id: 209103, nickname: "puf", name: "Frank van Puffelen" };
```

See the MDN page for full details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: What a fantastic power behind these "dots" !

Comment: I'm not completely used to them yet. Just like the singular `id` (which expands to `id: id`) I personally still prefer the more explicit syntax. But that might change over time.